# Celery relay message within a task

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery to implement communication from/to a RabbitMQ message queue. The basic setup works fine but now I am hitting some walls. I am doing some processing within the task execution and then try to post the result of the processing (while still being in the first celery task) to another celery bucket. This yield an error message which indicates that Celery gets somehow confused
`Received unregistered task of type 'text_extraction.extract'.`

My setup is like this:

Container-A: Receives "raw" input and does some basic extractiong

```
url = f"amqp://{MQ_USER}:{MQ_PASSWORD}@{MQ_HOST}:5672/{MQ_VHOST}"
celery = Celery("text_extraction", broker=url)

@celery.task
def extract(filename: str, encoded_base64: str):    
    # do some processing and get result
    result = {"text": "done!"}
    
    # relay result to MQ for another worker to pickup and persist results
    celery.send_task(f'store_data.store',
                     kwargs=result)
```

Container-B: Which should pick up the message:

```
url = f"amqp://{MQ_USER}:{MQ_PASSWORD}@{MQ_HOST}:5672/{MQ_VHOST}"
app = Celery("store_data", broker=url)

@app.task
def store(text: str):
    print("Received: ", text, flush=True)
```

Container-B does receive the message but some internal sanity checks seem to fail

```
Received unregistered task of type 'text_extraction.extract'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?
```

The error message is not helpful to me - I am running the code in separate containers. I want to post to a message queue and let the other worker pull the result from there but it seems to be a problem to do that as part of processing another message. What is the 'Celery' way of relaying messages and (partial) work results?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really stubled to this problem but generally a better idea (since you have a rabbitmq broker already set up) is to republish a new message from consumer1(probably to a separate queue) that will be consumed from consumer2.I think this is the best way that will save you from a lot of problems in the future too.

Shared tasks also can acomplish what you want but in my opinion is not the best option.

Comment: How would that look like? I had the impression this is what I am doing by sending the message to the `store_data.store`. this is a new message?